# my hard drive makes a clicking beeping sound when conected to Pi,but works fine on laptop?

Tags: raspbmc

when i connect my hard drive to my raspberry pi it makes like a clicking beeping sound and i cant use my mouse to access my films and the like,but if i connect hard drive to my laptop it works fine. This problem has only just started as it has worked fine for years,can anyone help please

Comment: Worked fine for years?  The Pi hasn't been around that long.

Comment: i have had mine for nearly 2 years

Comment: When did you last update the pi? and what distro is it running?

Comment: Sounds like either issues with power or kernel version (I recently had issues with an enclosure not working after a kernel update).

Comment: Hi gang thanks for your answers but im completely useless with regards to technology,how do i update the Pi and what is kernel,cheers

Comment: My boyfriends 2tb NTFS worked on the raspberry pi 3 but my 2tn FAT32 wouldn't read. It made the clicking noise as well. they are the same brand and style hdd? just different formats. Any help?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose your drive drains power from USB port, like most of 2"5: it does not work as PI does not give enough current on those ports. It the drive has its own power supply (most of 3"5), it should work fine.
Another option is to get a self-powered USB hub.